# Regex to search point numbers from the start of a list item from a list of strings

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a list of strings like:

> input_list =['1 . company','2.A . work report','3.1A . info','4 Jack and Jill','4.1 profit','11 loss','5 . 2014 works','A . considerations']

I wish to search only the starting point of a list item so that i will get the following output:

> 1
>   2.A
>   3.1A
>   4
>   4.1
>   11
>   5
>   A

I tried the code below:

```
input_list =['1 . company','2.A . work report','3.1A . info','4 Jack and Jill','4.1 profit','11 loss','5 . 2014 works','A . considerations']
for item in input_list:
   num_search = re.search(r'^\w+(\W)?(\w+)?\s',item)      
   num = num_search.group()
   print num
```

Output of the code is like:

> 1
>   2.A
>   3.1A
>   4 Jack
>   4.1
>   11
>   5
>   A

The problem in the above output is **4 Jack**. I want only **4**.

I think I have to use a different Regex for this purpose.

How can I get a generalized Regex to match all the points only??

Comment: Couldn't you just search until the first space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on what @MatsLindh is pointing out, [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) by space and get the first item:

```
>>> for item in input_list:
...     print(item.split(" ", 1)[0])
... 
1
2.A
3.1A
4
4.1
11
5
A
```

Comment: Thanks. this solves my purpose. No need for Regex here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with regex, you could use them in a (nested) list comprehension):

```
[m.group(0) for m in filter(None, [re.match(r'^([\d.A-Z]+)', i) for i in input_list])]
```

result:

```
['1', '2.A', '3.1A', '4', '4.1', '11', '5', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper regex could be

```
import re
input_list =['1 . company','2.A . work report','3.1A . info','4 Jack and Jill','4.1 profit','11 loss','5 . 2014 works','A . considerations']
for item in input_list:     
   num_search = re.search(r'^(\S+)',item) 
   if num_search:
     num = num_search.group()
   print num
```

Comment: just added a condition that if the search result is empty then don,t give the output, because it will throw an error.